# switching request and response using keyboard in SOAPUI

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, soapui, hotkeys, root

i'm using the free version of SoapUi 
i really want to switch from the request and response windows using keyboard only
i found that ctrl+alt+tab should do the work but it seems that the windows shortcut is blocking it
how can i work around this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Soapui version 5.2.0

Ctrl+tab - takes the cursor out of the active request/response.

Ctrl+tab+tab - switches the focus from request to response and vice versa if the cursor is not present in the active request/response.

Ctrl+tab+tab+tab - switches the focus from request to response and vice versa if the cursor is present in the active request/response.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Alt-Enter`

Here's a list of  SoapUI usage tips:

- http://kjetilvalle.com/posts/soapui-less-painful.html

Comment: i'm familiar with that page. as u can see in the bottom of the page the same question is asked there. Alt-Enter execute the request